# Trying to implement ListViewAnimations with ArrayAdapter<String>; cannot be instantiated

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, drag-and-drop

I am trying to write an app that for the initial part allows the user to enter a list of up to 8 words or phrases that will be used to trigger tasks. It tested successfully up to this point but now I am trying to use the library ListViewAnimations to allow the user to reorder the list and to remove items by swiping. I have taken the codeacademy java course and an edx intro to android programming class but I am mainly learning by googling and looking at tutorials with examples. 
This is what my original code looked like:

```js
package dtcj.bandtasker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    //create list of trigger phrases
    private ArrayList<String> items;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter;
    private ListView listItems;
   //Methods to read and write user entered items to the data file

    private void readItems() {
        File filesDir = getFilesDir();
        File triggerFile = new File(filesDir, "trigger.txt");
        try {
            items = new ArrayList<String>(FileUtils.readLines(triggerFile));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            items = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
    }

    private void writeItems() {
        File filesDir = getFilesDir();
        File triggerFile = new File(filesDir, "trigger.txt");
        try {
            FileUtils.writeLines(triggerFile, items);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listItems);
        items = new ArrayList<String>(8);
        readItems();
        itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                items);
        listItems.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);}
    
    //Add phrases to list
    public void onAddItem(View v) {
        //check that there are fewer than 8 trigger phrases in the array
        if (items.size() <= 7){
            EditText getNewItem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.getNewItem);
            String itemText = getNewItem.getText().toString();
            itemsAdapter.add(itemText);
            getNewItem.setText("");
            writeItems();}
        else{
            //Warn user they have reached maximum number of Trigger Phrases
            // Creating alert Dialog with one Button

            final AlertDialog.Builder maxAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            maxAlert.setMessage("Sorry! Eight is the maximum number of trigger phrases. Please delete a phrase before adding a new one.")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            //do things

                        }
                    });

            // Showing Alert Message
            maxAlert.show();


        }
    }
```

I don't need the appearance animations that the library offered but when I looked at a post from someone who couldn't get the drag and drop to work said they needed to first needed to include the code for the appearance animation which is this

```js
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter();
AlphaInAnimationAdapter animationAdapter = new AlphaInAnimationAdapter(myAdapter);
animationAdapter.setAbsListView(mListView);
mListView.setAdapter(animationAdapter);
```

I am trying to do that, but if I use
`import com.nhaarman.listviewanimations.ArrayAdapter;` instead of `import android.widget.Array Adapter` and try changing the code to this

```js
itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);
listItems.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
AlphaInAnimationAdapter animationAdapter = new AlphaInAnimationAdapter(this.itemsAdapter);
animationAdapter.setAbsListView(listItems);
listItems.setAdapter(animationAdapter);
```

Then I get Error:(60, 24) error: ArrayAdapter is abstract; cannot be instantiated. I tried declaring itemsAdapter as a new Adapter and as a new ListAdapter and that didn't work. I have imported other packages so that the total list now is

```js
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import com.nhaarman.listviewanimations.ArrayAdapter;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import com.nhaarman.listviewanimations.appearance.simple.AlphaInAnimationAdapter;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import com.nhaarman.listviewanimations.itemmanipulation.DynamicListView;
```

Any advice on how to correct this error would be greatly appreciated. I am sure it stems from some gaping hole in my understanding of java/android.

Thanks!
Taryn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many types of classes in Java. According to the error it seems like ArrayAdapter is an abstract class, and abstract classes cannot be instantiated directly. You need to intialise your itemsAdapter with a class that extends ArrayAdapter.

One thing you can do is create your own ItemsAdapter class that extends ArrayAdapter, implement the required methods and then initialise itemsAdapter with that class you created.

Take a look at this example. https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/blob/master/example/src/main/java/com/haarman/listviewanimations/itemmanipulation/DynamicListViewActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who needs it, this example was very helpful to me to see how to create a custom class http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter